# Send note to seller with PayPal buy now button

Tags: html, paypal

I have generated a "buy now" button from the paypal sandbox website as follows :

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc@xyz.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="BuyItNow">
            <input id="paypalamount" type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{totalprice}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
            <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
            <input type="image" src="img\paypal.png" border="0" name="submit" style="position:absolute;top:12px;left:10px">
</form>
```

When someone pays with the button, I want to send a default note to the seller. Is there a hidden field I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code you are looking for. Check out [variable list](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) for all the acceptable variables.

You need to edit your security settings in paypal for the note itself to show up, then do

`<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">`

A value of 1 will hide the box/prompt. It will appear on the checkout page. You can set up a buy now button to collect a text field entry, but you have to do that on set-up.

```
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Color" maxlength="200">Note
<input type="text" name="os1">
```

So if you have the no_note value correct (as you do in your code), you should look into your seller settings to make sure you are collecting instructions from customers.

Comment: I can see notes in the seller's account if i add notes from the checkout page.
But with the "cn" hidden filed, I do not see any notes.

Comment: cn is the note label (the prompt).

Comment: I think I was not clear in my questions, I want to put a custom note for the seller.
for example, every time someone pays, the seller gets a note " user xyz bought item a1 and a2"

Comment: You need to work with the IPN (instant payment notification). [See paypal's site}(https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/) I am not sure the actual message is able to be modified much, if at all. If IPN isn't on at all, though, that would be what I would try first (defaults). Usually it's a receipt with everything in detail.

Comment: the no_note and cn fields were depreciated in 2016. Now "custom" is the only way to get data through and it is not shown on the email or new website, only on IPN.